# iCal versus 'propose new meeting time'

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, exchange, calendar.app

We've got iCal talking to Exchange. When someone uses Outlook to send a 'propose alternative meeting time,' iCal (and Mail) pay no attention. Is there a solution?

Mail version is 4.3. iCal version is 4.0.3.

Comment: What versions of iCal/Exchange?

Comment: @JNK edited to supply.